# How to make files from an array of bytes and make zip from these files and send zip to the server without creating files in the storage of Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to send a zip file to the server.
I have to make files from the array of bytes and archive them in zip and send it to the server. 
BUT I don't need to create zip in Android storage.

How to do this??????????

By the way I use [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) to work with the server

Answer (score 0):

You could use `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream`. Which documentation to refer to of course depends on the version of java you're using.